# yeoman generator : repeat a prompt

Tags: generator, yeoman

i'm create a custom yeoman generator, i need create an array base on user responses :
How can i repeat a question and push answer to an array ?

ex :
Add a value ? Y/n
if yes
Value = ?

Add a value ? Y/n
...

for the moment, i have this code :

```
    MyGenerator.prototype.askFor = function askFor() {
  var cb = this.async();

  console.log(this.yeoman);

  var prompts = [

{
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'addvalue',
    message: 'Add value ?',
    default: true
  },
{
    name: 'myarray',
    message: 'Value =',
}
];

  this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.addvalue = props.addvalue;

    cb();
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Do you really need the confirm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeating Prompts with a Yeoman Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634349/repeating-prompts-with-a-yeoman-generator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a recursive function.

example (won't work as is because of `this` context):

```
function askSomething() {
    this.prompt({ /* some prompts */ }, function (answers) {
        // call the function back if needed
        askSomething();
    });
}
```

Comment: i have other questions, i don't want to repeat all questions.

Comment: Just recurse over a part of the prompt using multiple prompt functions inside your generator. Basic programmation. You can check the `yo` command line tool repository, it is doing recursion over prompts.

Comment: Sadly this fails when you try and write an automated test.